# Cruising Alaska & Canada: do I need visas for both countries?

Tags: visas, usa, canada, cruising

I'm from Russia. I am planning to cruise Alaska, but the itinerary includes a Canadian port of call.

I have obtained US visitors visa so that I can board the ship in Seattle.

Do I need a separate Canadian visitors visa, as well?

Answer (score 9):

[According to Carnival](https://help.carnival.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/1405/session/L3RpbWUvMTQ5MDUwNzgxOC9zaWQvZlVvaElqbmM3U19jWnA2cTQ0T0Y2YnRHYjNxazB2dVVrTlNMUVJabW5ZNDh5eHl0NkxBYjREZVpXMXdxdVdQVnFUN1VmTWtPbE1IVVdOUF9lbFdVYVhIal9HWXdtbjVzVWNlTUdBbFRySjlOT3dCY3IwRHgwZk1RJTIxJTIx), you need a Canadian visa if the ship stops at a Canadian port of call, even if you do not go ashore.

> - Non-U.S. Citizens must carry a passport valid for at least three months beyond the date of their visit to Canada, from their country of citizenship.
> - Non-U.S Citizens may require a Canadian Visa depending on their nationality.
> - Guests who are not citizens of the United States, Canada, U.K., Australia or New Zealand, may require a Temporary Resident Visa (TRV) to visit or transit Canada.
> - If guests are required to have a visa, it must be obtained in advance regardless of whether they choose to remain onboard or go ashore. Processing times vary by citizenship and may take up to 45 days. For more information, regarding travel documentation requirements, please contact your local Canadian consulate or visit http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/visit/apply-who.asp.

Comment: Princess also required a Canadian visa several years ago for an Alaskan cruises that stopped in Canada.